# Create SSL certificate for use in my application

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

Made a simple server using TcpListen and would like to add SSL to the applicayion for security.

I need help in the actual steps needed to create a self signed certificate, and what problems if any would there be if I shared the application.

Would the user have to make their own certificate or if using the same one would cause a security issue im guessing, as the certificate would readable if I shared the application or can you hide it in the application itself.

Any question answered is a step closer :)

Thanks

**UPDATED**

Im having a little trouble with makecert. Which type do i want ...

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Your Name" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -ss My`

OR

`makecert -r -n "CN=Your Name" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -sv selfcert.pvk selfcert.cer
cert2spc selfcert.cer selfcert.spc
pvkimprt -pfx selfcert.spc selfcert.pvk`

And what values need to be edited??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

> http://www.somacon.com/p42.php

Or even easier:

> http://www.inventec.ch/chdh/notes/14.htm

For when you're ready to pay:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/4stepsSSL.aspx

Hope that helps!

Comment: Updated question would like further help please!

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the packets yourself without having to implement a SSL cert.  Just pass all outgoing and incoming packets through a de/encrypt method, and do the same on the client side.

Comment: Why would you do it at the application layer instead of the transport layer?

Comment: I dont know :) Im learning and thought SSL was the way to go to secure data when a client connects to my server! Dont really want to use de/encrypt as its mostly php that access the server and dont want the script knowing the key. Thanks anyways